# header for fopen visual studio 2015 community edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

As per MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx

for "fopen" I need to include required header : `<stdio.h>`

However, my below code gives error: "identifier fopen is unidentified"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
int main()
{
char * buffer = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("C:\Documents and Settings\psps.txt", "r");

return 0;
}
```

What should I include to perform file-related operation?

Comment: it compiles in visual-studio 2010

Comment: the MSDN page you referenced says <stdio.h>, so why aren't you including it?

Comment: Have you tried using `std::fopen`?

Comment: Compiles fine for me in 2015 community once I escaped the backslashes in the filename.  Of course we have no way of knowing what you have in the precompiled header.

Comment: MS is making life difficult for C++ programmer those who use VS.

Comment: not really.  if you want to use the c++ library version, then use [std::fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen).  if you want to use the c library version, then follow the MSDN instructions.  this is not a microsoft issue.  you're using the c++ header and the c library.

Comment: std::fopen is also not working for me. Not sure what's the problem

Comment: What is the exact compiler output with the error that you're seeing?  As I sad, it compiled for me after I corrected the filename.  If you haven't escaped those backslashes in your code then it's not surprising it doesn't work, but it isn't because of fopen.  What happens if you remove the precompiled header?

Answer (score 0):

You could try including `<stdio.h>` as you mentioned.  Or, you could include `<cstdio>` as you're currently doing and then use `std::fopen()` instead.

When C++ headers wrap the standard library functions in the `std` namespace.

The other option is to include `<fstream>` and learn your way around the C++ file streaming classes (see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).